# Find text line1 in spreadsheet and get column 2

Tags: linux, bash, file, awk

I'm trying to show the field next to the name that I find with awk command in spredsheet.xls

I have this situation;

```
  **Column1**               *Column2* 

  **PIPPO**    *pippo@gmail.com darth@gmail.com*
  **PLUTO**    *pluto@gmail.com duck@gmail.com*
  **WATER**    *drink@gmail.com water@gmail.com*
```

how do I search for a word in column 1 and display the contents in column 2?

```
awk '$1 == "PIPPO"' spreadsheet.xls
```

this command show:

```
PIPPO    pippo@gmail.com darth@gmail.com
```

---

#### Update

this is my code ---- Column1 (PIPPO, PLUTO, WATER) and awkvar is the same thing----

```
for fullname in /*.zip; do 
filename="${fullname##*/}" 
awkvar=$(echo $filename | cut -d_ -f2-2) 
awk -v var="$awkvar" '{print $2,$3}' spreadsheet.xls 
done
```

but this not work. How do I put a pattern variable in awk?

**Update 2**

i have update list xls with comma separated

FIELD1,pippo@gmail.com,darth@gmail.com
FIELD1,pippo@gmail.com,darth@gmail.com,sampei@gmail.com

```
output=(awk -F ',' -v var="$awkvar" '$1==var {print $2,$3,$4} spreadsheet.txt)
```

but awk delete some letters at the beginning of the output

```
echo "$output"
```

- ippo@gmail.com darth@gmail.com
- pippo@gmail.com darth@gmail.com sampei@gmail.com

but if i remove $4

```
output=(awk -F ',' -v var="$awkvar" '$1==var {print $2,$3} spreadsheet.txt)

echo "$output"
```

it is correct display for line1 but not for line2:

- pippo@gmail.com darth@gmail.com
- pippo@gmail.com darth@gmail.com

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
awk '$1=="PIPPO" {print $2}' file
```

That will output:

```
pippo@gmail.com
```

The format is not clear to me, so depending on how it is you may need `{print $2, $3}`.

---

As said in comments, based on your updated code you can use this to use the bash var inside `awk`:

```
awk -v var="$awkvar" '$1==var {print $2,$3}' spreadsheet.xls
```

Comment: Ok, is fine, but i have in column2 from 2 to 20 adress emails.
After i get output and put it in mail command

Comment: OK, so is this working to you? It's not clear to me.

Comment: Well, @pasaico, first of all I need to get a confirmation from you that the input text is *exactly* as it shows now in the question. Are the `*` really appearing? Then I will update my answer :)

Comment: this is my code:

`for fullname in /*.zip; do
    filename="${fullname##*/}"
    awkvar=$(echo $filename | cut -d_ -f2-2)
awk -v var="$awkvar" '{print $2,$3}' spreadsheet.xls
done`

but this not work.
How i put pattern variable in awk?

Comment: Please update your question with this code and a proper formatting of the sample input, as I asked before. Otherwise it is difficult to read the code.

Comment: OK. I still don't see a proper input code, but... Whatever. For your sample code I would use `awk -v var="$awkvar" '$1==var {print $2,$3}' spreadsheet.xls`

Comment: Thank you very much
but your "but...Whatever" not learn me much!
again Thank you!

Comment: Nice to read that, @pasaico :) Don't get me wrong, the "whatever" was because I was expecting to see the sample input code with proper format! But if your issue is already solved it's more than fine, of course. Cheers.

Comment: @pasaico if you have a new question,  [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) please. This is very different from the first one.

Comment: Sorry again, can you check one more time UPDATE2?
thank you and 
Merry Christmas :P

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to display only 2nd column. Use this awk:

```
awk '$1 == "PIPPO" {print $2}' spreadsheet.xls
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to display all columns after 1st columns then use:

```
sed -n 's/^PIPPO *//p' spreadsheet.xls
pippo@gmail.com darth@gmail.com
```