# check mail with space

Tags: regex, bash, email

I have some emails with a space between one and the other
sometimes even single email... this is situation example:

1. line1 - yyy@zzz.com sss@xxx.it ddd@rrr.biz yyy@zzz.pr ecc. ecc.
2. line2 - yyy@ddd.com (without the final space)
   ecc.ecc.

thi is my code:

```
regex="^[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}"
if [[ "$mail" =~ $regex ]];
then
    echo "OK $mail"
else
    echo "WARNING CHECK: $mail"
fi
done
```

how do I enter the space in regex without that will give me error when a single email?

**Update 2**

i have update list xls with comma separated

- line1 - FIELD1,pippo@gmail.com,darth@gmail.com
- line2 - FILED1,pippo@gmail.com,darth@gmail.com,sampei@gmail.com

output=(awk -F ',' -v var="$awkvar" '$1==var {print $2,$3,$4} spreadsheet.txt)

but awk delete some letters at the beginning of the output

echo "$output"

```
 ippo@gmail.com darth@gmail.com
pippo@gmail.com darth@gmail.com sampei@gmail.com
```

but if i remove $4

output=(awk -F ',' -v var="$awkvar" '$1==var {print $2,$3} spreadsheet.txt)

echo "$output"

it is correct display for line1 but not for line2:

```
pippo@gmail.com darth@gmail.com
pippo@gmail.com darth@gmail.com
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, it wuld probably be a best idea to standardize your data in order to validate each email separately

Comment: I don't understand what your desired result is. Are all the email addresses in your sample text OK?

Comment: @glennjackman yes, all in a spreadsheet.xls

Comment: You're trying to get a bash script to read an Excel spreadsheet?!? Good luck.

Comment: @glennjackman oh, yes and fine work [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702384/find-text-line1-in-spreadsheet-and-get-column-2)

Comment: @glennjackman can you check my UPDATE2? thank you

Comment: Does your file contain DOS line endings? A trailing carriage return would account for the first letter being over-written with a space

Comment: >file spreadsheet.txt
>spreadsheet.txt ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

Comment: @glennjackman thank you, the problem was that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data line by line into an array (each word in the line is space-separated):

```
re='^[[:alnum:]_.+-]+@[[:alnum:]_.+-]+\.[[:alnum:]]{2,4}$'
while read -ra addresses; do
     for addr in "${addresses[@]}"; do
         if [[ $addr =~ $re ]]; then
             echo "OK $addr"
         else
             echo "WARNING CHECK: $addr"
         fi
     done
done <<END
yyy@zzz.com sss@xxx.it ddd@rrr.biz yyy@zzz.pr ecc. ecc.
yyy@ddd.com ecc.ecc.
a@b.c
first@last
name@subdomain.domain.com
END
```

```
OK yyy@zzz.com
OK sss@xxx.it
OK ddd@rrr.biz
OK yyy@zzz.pr
WARNING CHECK: ecc.
WARNING CHECK: ecc.
OK yyy@ddd.com
WARNING CHECK: ecc.ecc.
WARNING CHECK: a@b.c
WARNING CHECK: first@last
OK name@subdomain.domain.com
```

Validating email addresses is trickier that it looks. This is a valid email address:

```
(Glenn Jackman) "Glenn Jackman" @ some.domain.example.com
```

Comment: `postbox@com` is a valid email address, as well as `abcdefghi@abc.museum`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Answer (score 2):

You can use `egrep -o` to capture each email separately using same regex as you have:

```
> s='yyy@zzz.com sss@xxx.it ddd@rrr.biz yyy@zzz.pr'
> egrep -o "[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}" <<< "$s"
yyy@zzz.com
sss@xxx.it
ddd@rrr.biz
yyy@zzz.pr
```

**EDIT:** I would like to add here that `email addresses can contain spaces (between quotes)`

Comment: BTW the regex will not consider many valid email addresses. The allowed addresses are much more complex than this

Comment: Of of course email addresses have much going into them. I just reused OP's regex to break apart a line into individual email addresses.

Comment: I know I just wanted to point it out. Also: email addresses can contain spaces (between quotes). I would just add a warning to the answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your comment in `update 2`. Can you provide a sample of `spreadsheet.xls` in your question as well.

Comment: is a simple txt file with comma separated email

Comment: But your sample file in question is space separated not comma separated.